B-Splines in KANs: How Are They Implemented?
Can someone help me understand how Kolmogorov-Arnold Networks (KANs) make use of B-splines? They talk about spline grids in the paper without explicitly defining what they mean by it AFAIK. For instance they say:

Update of spline grids. We update each grid on the fly according to its input activations, to address the issue that splines are
defined on bounded regions but activation values can evolve out of the
fixed region during training.


Do KANs keep track of input activation statistics in every batch?

Do they use mini-batches or do they simply use the whole dataset?

How does changing input activations change the splines?


Relevant equations:
$$\phi(x) = w_b b(x) + w_s \text{spline}(x)$$
$$b(x) = \text{silu}(x) = \frac{x}{1 + e^{-x}}$$
$$\text{spline}(x) = \sum_i c_i B_i(x)$$
If you could help me under the underlying idea behind B-splines and basis functions / spline grids, that would be very nice! I am interested in the details.
